# Error while loading shared libraries, no such file or directory

Tags: linux

I know there are a ton of similar questions but none of them seem to be working for me.

```
error while loading shared libraries: libquickly.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

[]$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/lib

[]$ ls /usr/local/lib
 ...
 libquickly.so
 libquickly.so.1.1
 ...
```

I have tried running ldconfig and that did not seem to make a difference. I tried removing libquickly.so.1.1 and adding a new syslink with the same name and it did not seem to make a difference. I also noticed that if I close out my terminal window and open a new one and do echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH it shows it as empty and I have to redo to the export command to add /usr/local/lib back in. Could that be part of the problem?

Comment: Some programs (one out of 100) are hard coded to look for libraries in `/usr/lib(64)/` only. Suggest : Install  libquickly to /usr/ .  ( #  `cp libquickly.so.1.1 /usr/lib(64)/` ).

Comment: That worked, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some programs (one out of 100) are hard coded to look for libraries in `/usr/lib(64)/` only.

Suggest : Install libquickly to /usr/ . ( Or # `cp libquickly.so.1.1 /usr/lib(64)/` ).